# Apache with PHP-FPM - PHP doesn't execute

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, centos7, php7

I have compiled PHP 7 with FPM support using [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/) on CentOS 7.x environment.

I was able to test the php through CLI by running.

```
cd /opt/php7/bin
./php --version
```

Which outputs

```
PHP 7.0.6 (cli) (built: May 22 2016 07:20:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

I have also installed apache and it is running successfully.

Now I have created vhosts and guided domain to a directory. I have pasted a php file `info.php` with the function `phpinfo()` but server outputs the PHP function without executing it.

I feel I am really close now and just need to configure apache to run with php-fpm so I put this config on `httpd.conf` file but it doesn't help.

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.shtml index.cgi index.php

    AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp7 .php
    Action application/x-httpd-fastphp7 /php7-fcgi

    Alias /php7-fcgi /opt/php7/bin/php-cgi

    FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/html/ -socket /opt/php7/var/run/php-fpm.pid -pass-header Authorization

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

fcgi module is installed beacuse when I run `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` I get `fcgid_module (shared)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. I have followed the steps below.

### Make Sure PHP-FPM is running

First of all if you haven't choose any alternative port for php-fpm then it will be set to run at port 9000.

```
/etc/init.d/php-fpm start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/php7.x-fpm start
```

If it fails saying that the port is already occupied then you will need to find out the process number that is running by the port and *kill* it.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :8999
```

This should give you the process id that is currently running. For example if the process id is `21190` then you run

```
kill 21190
```

Now that the port is cleared you can now try to start the `php-fpm` again

```
/etc/init.d/php-fpm start
```

### Update vHost config file

For example you are hosting `example.com`. Now open up the vhost config for the domain. Here is a simplest example.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example.com/"
    ServerName example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now add update it with following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example.com/"
    ServerName example.com

    # Setup php-fpm to process php files
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example.com/$1
    DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

And now all your php file for the example.com should execute.

**Reference:** https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM